# Setting Assoc Array from Function to use througough page

Tags: php, arrays, associative

How would I setup an associative array to reference specific values at different sections of a page. My function:

```
<?php
function park_data($park_page_id) {
    $data = array();
    if($park_page_id){
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `park_profile` WHERE `park_id` = $park_page_id"));
        return $data;
    }
}
?>
```

My `print_r`:

```
<?php
print_r (park_data(1));
?>
```

Produces the following associative array:

```
Array ( [park_id] => 1 [park_name] => Kenai Fjords [park_address] => 1212 4th Avenue [park_city] => Seward [park_state] => Alaska [park_zip] => 99664)
```

How would I print just the `[park_name]` value from this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

```
// on PHP 5.4
print_r(park_data(1)['park_name']);

// earlier versions
$tmp = park_data(1);
print_r($tmp['park_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$park=park_data(1);  
echo $park['park_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

To output custom formatted text in general, and in this case to output only a single array's key value, use `echo`, because `print_r()` called on an array displays the whole array's structure and content, and that's not what you want:

```
<?php
    // code
    $park_data=park_data(1);
    echo $park_data["park_name"];
    // code
?>
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'`

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='`, and the same one will still apply above after you fix this one.